# visualforce error page for lightning

Tags: visualforce, lightning

i try to do the same thing in salesforce lightning but it does not work
any help please ???

**Controller**

```
public class OLGAerrorPage {
     public OLGAerrorPage (){
        ApexPages.addmessage(new ApexPages.message(ApexPages.severity.FATAL,'Please enter a future closing date'));
     }
}
```

**visualforce page:**

```
<apex:page controller="OLGAerrorPage"  >
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="https://www.lightningdesignsystem.com/assets/styles/slds.css"/>

<style>
.msgIcon {
    display: none!important
}
.customMessage * {
    color: #fff!important
}
.customMessage {
    margin: 5px 0!important;
    max-width: 1280px;
    opacity: 1!important;
    width: 100%;
    font-size: 12px;
    border: 0px;
    padding-left: 10px;
}
.message {
    opacity: .1
}
</style>


<script>
     $(document).ready(function(){
       overridePageMessages();    
    });

    function overridePageMessages(){    
        var textureEffect = '';
        //Uncomment below line for texture effect on page messages
        textureEffect = 'slds-theme--alert-texture';


        $('.errorM3').addClass('slds-notify slds-notify--alert slds-theme--error customMessage '+textureEffect);                  


        $('.errorM3').removeClass('errorM3'); 

    }
</script>
<apex:pagemessages/>
</apex:page>
```

---

i try to do the same thing in salesforce lightning but it does not work
any help please ???

Comment: Where do you want to use this VF Page in lightning ?

Comment: yes i want to use this VF Page in lightning any idea please ?